# PayPal Adaptive Payment - angelleye CodeIgniter Library

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to run the sample project from https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-codeigniter; but am unable to get to function as it throws the following error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input

Filename: paypal/Paypal_adaptive.php

Line Number: 396
```

Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you must be getting an empty result back from the API request.  This most likely means you're running into a problem with your server software stack.

PayPal's sandbox only accepts requests via the TLS 1.2 protocol.  The live servers will be the same next year.

See [this article of mine](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ssl-error-poodle-vulnerability/) for more details, most importantly...

> If you want to use TLS 1.2 you’ll need to upgrade to OpenSSL 1.0.1 as a minimum, and then you’ll be able to set CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to 6 (TLS 1.2).
>
> If you want TLS 1.2 to be used automatically during SSL requests, you’ll also need to upgrade to PHP 5.5.19+ (this is the ideal solution but many projects are still on older PHP versions).

So the first thing I would check is your software versions.

Comment: Hey Andrew.

Thank you for your reply.

If the application is on a local server, do I need to any additional set up?

I'm running php 7.0.0 (running MAMP on Mac OS X).

Comment: Can you verify what version of OpenSSL you're running?

Comment: Hey Andrew. Turns out I wasn't using the 1.0.2h version for curl.

After updating it to 1.0.2, I can confirm it to be working.

Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: if it solve the problem can you make it as an answer?